# Xcode UI test is generating and running new app MyAppUITests?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have an Obj-C project that I'm adding a UI Test target to. Because I'm using Network Extensions I can't use automatic code signing. When I created the UI Test target I selected Swift as the language. (Although I've tried Obj-C as well.) It defaulted to using automatic code signing and caused me a lot of problems trying to figure out how to get around that. I have created a signing profile with the id of com.company.MyAppUITest instead of the automatically created com.company.MyAppUITests. Although you can't see that profile in the dev portal it seems to be there as it won't let me manually create one with an id of com.company.MyAppUITests. So I have resolved the code signing issue with the UI Test target. My problem is that when I go to Product > Test it builds an app with a generic icon called MyAppUITest and runs that instead of running MyApp.

Xcode 8.3.3

iOS 10.3.2

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly normal that Xcode installs a new application with a generic icon that has the name of your UI Testing target. It's this application that will be in charge of launching your application when executing the following code

```
// Swift
XCUIApplication().launch()

// Objective-C
[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init] launch];
```

Of course it will only work if you set the Target Application's setting of your target

[image]